# How to increase size of an ubuntu cloud image

Tags: ubuntu, disk-image, cloud, qemu, virsh

I have been trying to start a VM using ubuntu cloud images. Now, the image size is very less, I am getting around only 2GB of space. Is there any way to increase the size? I tried qemu-img resize, but it doesn't work, as I am not able to reallocate the space from inside the VM.

TIA.

Answer (score 5):

I will be talking based on some quick QEMU experiments along the following setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

**`qemu-img`**

As of 18.04, the cloud images are already in qcow2 format, so the following seemed to work:

```
qemu-img resize ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img +128G
```

The guest appeared to immediately pick this new size up.

**`growpart`**

This script claims to make a given partition fill up as much space as possible and might be of use:

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-guest-utils
sudo growpart /dev/vda 1
```

It seems to run happily even though /dev/vda1 was mounted at /.

Answer (score 2):

The growroot package is designed to do exactly that. http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/trusty/admin/cloud-initramfs-growroot

If not already installed, add it with `apt-get install cloud-initramfs-growroot` and reboot your instance. The root partition will be expanded to the full size of your virtual disk (the one that you extended using qemu-img).

Comment: For me it says "Unsupported platform on EFI system, doing nothing".

Comment: This seems to be already installed on the Ubuntu 16.04 cloud image.  At least it worked for me and I didn't have to do any apt install.